# check volume level on android using adb commands

Tags: android, adb

I want to check volume level on android via ADB commands...Does anyone knows such commands?
I know the commands to increase and decrease volume but how to check whether it is working or not using only the adb commands.

Comment: you have console access of android device?

Answer (score 1):

Values are stored in the **com.android.providers.settings** package database.
You need to be rooted and have the sqlite3 binary available.

```sh
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db \
  "select * from system where name like '%volume%';"
```